# Concatenate strings for open a window popup with <a> control

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a popup passing two parameter numbers: 2239 and 2. I will replace them by two variables.

I'm trying to use  html control , but I don't know how to concatenate them in a string.

No problem with that:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenPopup(2239,2);">click here/a>
```

I get error with this:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenPopup(" + "2239" + "," + "2" + ");">click here/a>
```

This is my OpenPopup function:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function OpenPopup(p1, p2) {
            var cad = 'AutosPopup.aspx?cod_op=' + p1 + '&orden=' + p2;
            window.open(cad, 'newWindowId', 'width=800'+',height=400');
            return false;
        }

 </script>
```

Comment: The second one errors because you're sending in 1 parameter. Since the comma is inside quotes, it does not delimiter the params. Also, your question is very unclear.

Comment: Would you mind to put an example on how to write the second one?

Comment: I don't understand what the second one is supposed to accomplish

Comment: Are you trying to variably set the arguments int the function?

Comment: Yes, instead of numbers 2239 and 2, I will change them for variables n1 and n2.

Comment: `onclick="javascript:OpenPopup(n1,n2);"` ???

Comment: Thank you, now I realize my question was very silly. chr(13) Finally this is what I done: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenPopup(<%# Eval("Cod_OP") %>,<%# Eval("Orden") %>);">Incluye Autos del Pleno</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="OpenPopup('2239','2');">click here</a>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nw6dG/1/